# Auto calling a key map in Vim on start

Tags: vim, autoresize

I've been using Vim along with WinWalker, a Buffer manager. There's one big feature which is automatic resizing for splitted windows. So, when I focus a buffer, it resizes to the maximum width and height.

However, to activate this feature, you need to hit `ctrl+w` to pop up the WinWalker commands (though it can be mapped to another key) and then hit `c` to activate the autoresizing (so you could hit `ctrl+w` and c right after the combo). This is really tedious, specially when you already have more than one buffer opened, when you have to activate the autoresizing in each buffer.

My question is: **is there a way to call automatically this key combination in .vimrc?**

I've tried something like `autocmd VimEnter <C-W>c`, but it just doesn't work. Besides, I'm not really good at customizing Vim. So, could anybody help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to do it to call the function that `<C-W>c` calls.  The only ways I know how to discover the desired function is either with `:map` or by looking at the source code.  The command `:map` will show all the current key bindings.  I doubt this will tell you everything you want, but it should tell you what `<C-W>` is mapped to, which could tell you where to look in the source code.

Also, make sure and read any help files provided with WinWalker.  The author may have set up a mechanism to start with the feature on.  If this is the case, it may be as simple as defining a variable in your .vimrc.

Comment: Exactly, I found out that <C-W> was calling WinWalkerMenu(), and in a while true loop it was waiting for inputs, so when you hit c, it jumps to a case. Actually, this is a secondary feature in WinWalker( _"Oh and by the way, it autoresizes too, though it's not relevant"_ ) so there is no direct function to activate it by default. Would then be a way to :call WinWalker() and "simulate" a `c` input?

Comment: @Kor I'm not familiar with any way to simulate user input in a vim script (.vimrc).  I'm not saying it doesn't exist, I just don't know how to do it.  What I would do if I was in your position is abstract out the functionality to a function and submit a patch to the author.

Comment: @Kor I went ahead and modified the script.  I don't use WinWalker, so I'm not sure if it works like it's supposed to, but you can test it out if you want.  I've uploaded it to a git repo at https://github.com/karategeek6/WinWalkerClone  Only the plugins/WinWalker.vim file is modified.  The function to call is WinWalkerAutoWindowResize().